# What is the name of this house plant with textured leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I've tried every search term online to find this plant to no avail. Does anyone out there know its name?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome GTKZ! I just want to let you know that we don't use all-capital letters here so I took them out. Since we're different than some other sites, I invite you to have a look at the pages of our [help]. If you have any questions about how to use the site, please leave a note and someone will come along and help you!

Answer (score 3):

It is a Pilea variety, specifically Pilea 'Norfolk' see here http://www.costafarms.com/plants/pilea.

This plant likes bright light but will do okay in semi shade - it will not appreciate direct sunlight in high summer, particularly during the middle part of the day. Needs average warmth, minimum 50degF in winter. Water liberally from spring through to fall, but allow the potting soil to dry out slightly between waterings - should feel just dry to the touch. Water sparingly in winter, and use tepid water year round if you can. Likes high humidity, so mist the leaves regularly and don't stand near heat sources like radiators.

Comment: Thank you! With your info, I was able to find more about Pilea Spruceana Norfolk.